# An Inequality of harmonic series

Tags: calculus

How would you prove $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k} \gt \int_1^{n+1} \dfrac{1}{k} \, dk$ without using any brute-force?

Applying Integral test to the series, I got a similar kind of inequality but that doesn't prove it.

Comment: I'd say it's obvious that $$\frac1k>\int_k^{k+1}\frac{dx}x.$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Are you saying 1/k  > log(1+1/k) ? How does that help to prove it?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{k}\forall x\in [k,k+1]$; $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}\forall x\in [k,k+1]$, compare these two functions. By the way, what do you mean by brute-force?

Comment: Combine @TonyMa's comment ($\frac1x$ is a decreasing function) with induction

Comment: @TonyMa Is $f(x)$ any different from $g(x)$ ?

Comment: If you graph the series $1/k$ as a stair-step function (e.g. it's $1$ from $x=1$ to $2$ and it's $1/2$ from $x=2$ to $3$, etc) and graph $1/x$ on top of it, I think you'll see right away what Lord Shark is saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is that
(1) $\int_a^b f(x) dx > 0$
if $f(x)$ is continuous on
$[a, b]$
and $f(x) > 0$
for
$a < x < b$
and
(2)
if $a < b < c$
and $f$ is integrable then
$\int_a^b f(x) dx+\int_b^c f(x) dx
=\int_a^c f(x) dx$.

Then
$\dfrac1{k}-\int_k^{k+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}
=\int_k^{k+1}(\dfrac1{k}- \dfrac1{t})dt
\gt 0
$
since
$\dfrac1{k}- \dfrac1{t}
=\dfrac{t-k}{kt}
\gt 0$
for $k < t < k+1$.

Summing,

$\begin{array}\\
0
&\lt \sum_{k=1}^n (\int_k^{k+1}(\dfrac1{k}- \dfrac1{t})dt)\\
&\lt \sum_{k=1}^n (\dfrac1{k}-\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac1{t}dt)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \int_k^{k+1}\dfrac1{t}dt\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k}- \int_1^{n+1}\dfrac1{t}dt\\
\end{array}
$

which is what you want.

Comment: Nice answer. From which theorem you set the condition (1) & (2) ?

Comment: Experience. I assume what is sufficient to derive the desired conclusion. Also, this way I don't need to specify any particular type of integral (another of the many subjects I don't know too much about).

Answer (score 1):

As some comments have pointed out above:

A way to prove it is using the definition of Riemann integral and some properties about it.

You have that $\int_a^b f(x) dx \leq U(f,P)=\sum_{i \in P}|p_i-p_{i-1}|  \sup_{x \in [p_i-1,p_i]}\left\{ f(x) \right\}$  where $P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$.

Now you can define $[a,b]=[1,n+1]$ and as a partition you can choose $P=\left\{ [1,2],[2,3],[3,4],...,[n,n+1]  \right\}$ and the inequality follow.

A good way to visualize the situation is to draw the graph of $1/x$

Comment: +1 I would even put the last sentence first, along with a picture showing the area and the bounding Riemann sum. Then the actual algebra could be left to the reader.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, thank you for your advise, I often find myself unsure on how much to write and how much leave as "exercise for the reader".